# Frame inside another frame In python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying to place frame inside a frame.... like i want to place buttoncontainer and buttoncontainer2 inside the bodycontainer frame. But when i do so bodycontainer vanished,.. i cant figure out my problem.. i know i am doing some silly mistake.... Please help me to figure out this problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Apps')
root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 500))

headerbanner=Frame(root,width=790,height=50,highlightbackground="gray",highlightthickness=1)
headerbanner.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=2)

bodycontainer=Frame(root,width=790,height=380,highlightbackground="gray",highlightthickness=1)
bodycontainer.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=0)

buttoncontainer=Frame(bodycontainer,width=50,height=300,highlightbackground="gray",highlightthickness=1)
buttoncontainer.grid(row=0,column=0)
buttoncontainer2=Frame(bodycontainer,width=50,height=300,highlightbackground="gray",highlightthickness=1)
buttoncontainer2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq5r7.png)

[Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lniS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grid()` geometry manager will shrink a frame to fit the contained widgets. Therefore it looks like the frame has disappeared. You can stop this size propagation with `grid_propagate(False)`. See my example below. I have given each frame a different color to show where they are:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Tkinter Apps')
root.resizable(width=TRUE, height=TRUE)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 500))

headerbanner=Frame(root,width=790,height=50,bg='khaki')
headerbanner.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=2)

bodycontainer=Frame(root,width=790,height=380,bg='tan')
bodycontainer.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=5,pady=0)
bodycontainer.grid_propagate(False) # Stop grid() from resizing bodycontainer

buttoncontainer=Frame(bodycontainer,width=50,height=300,bg='powder blue')
buttoncontainer.grid(row=0,column=0)
buttoncontainer2=Frame(bodycontainer,width=50,height=300,bg='olivedrab1')
buttoncontainer2.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes... it works... thank you so much.....