# Python tkinter Frame with multiple widgets within another Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to position one of my python tkinter Frames (`ButtonWindow`) within my other Frame (`MainWindow`), so that when I run the app the widgets in `ButtonWindow` are present in `MainWindow` along with the `MainWindow` widget.

In the code below the Buttons from `ButtonWindow` are present along with the `MainWindow` Label, but the `ButtonWindow` Label is missing.

I looked at the answers in [Frame inside another frame In python Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784698/frame-inside-another-frame-in-python-tkinter) and tried to set the background to purple to understand where the borders of `ButtonWindow` actually are, but I can't see any purple?

Thanks for any help!

```
import tkinter as tk 

class ButtonWindow(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bd = 5
        self.bg = "purple"
        self.label = tk.Label(text="Button window", font=12)
        for i in range(3):
            self.button = ttk.Button(text="button", command= lambda: button_fun())
            self.button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        
    def button_fun(self):
        pass
                          

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(text="Main Window", font=12)
        self.label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.button_window = ButtonWindow()
        self.button_window.pack()
  
app = MainWindow()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You aren't actually placing anything inside either of your Frames.  The first parameter to all widget constructors is the parent widget, the default is the root window.

Comment: Other than the above issue, you have never called any layout function on `self.label` ("Button window") inside `ButtonWindow`. Also `self.bd = 5` and `self.bg = "purple"` do not change the border width and background color of `ButtonWindow`.  Use `self.config(bd=5, bg="purple")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to specify the parent of widgets when creating them, otherwise they will be children of root window.

Also you have never called any layout function on the *"Button window"* label so it is not visible.

`self.bd = 5` and `self.bg = "purple"` will not change the border width and the background color.  Use `self.config(bd=5, bg="purple")` instead.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ButtonWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(bd=5, bg="purple") # replace self.bd = 5 and self.bg = "purple"
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Button window", font=12, fg='white', bg='purple') # specify parent
        self.label.pack() # pack the label, otherwise it is not visible
        for i in range(3):
            self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="button", command=self.button_fun) # specify parent
            self.button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def button_fun(self):
        pass


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Window", font=12) # specify parent
        self.label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        self.button_window = ButtonWindow(self) # specify parent
        self.button_window.pack()

root = tk.Tk() # create root window explicitly
MainWindow(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also I have changed `command=lambda: button_fun()` to `command=self.button_fun`.  The former one will raise exception when any of the buttons is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want is create a Main Frame with another frame inside it which include 3 buttons.

In this case, I changed a little bit your code to do that. One of the changes was replace the `tk.Label` for the `tk.LabelFrame` (This corrects the Label that was missing in the `ButtonWindow` as you stated).

The second change that I suggest is to pass the `MainFrame` to the `ButtonWindow` as a parent frame. To do this I created the `myCoreFrame` inside the `MainWindow`class. Also, for all widgets I've set a parent frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ButtonWindow():   

    def __init__(self, Frame, *args, **kwargs):
        self.label = tk.LabelFrame(Frame, text="Button window", font=12, bg = "purple")
        self.label.pack()
        for i in range(3):
            self.button = tk.Button(self.label, text="button", command= lambda: button_fun())
            self.button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
        
def button_fun(self):
    pass
                          

class MainWindow():   

    def __init__(self, window, *args, **kwargs):
        
        myCoreFrame = tk.Frame(window)
        myCoreFrame.pack()
        
        self.label = tk.LabelFrame(myCoreFrame, text="Main Window", font=12, bg = "red")
        self.label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.button_window = ButtonWindow(self.label)

root = tk.Tk()
app = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't putting the labels and buttons inside frames. You need to explicitly set the frame as the parent of the button and label. If you don't, the widgets become children of the root window.

```
class ButtonWindow(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Button window", font=12)
        #                     ^^^^^^
        for i in range(3):
            self.button = ttk.Button(self, text="button", command= lambda: button_fun())
            #                        ^^^^^^
        ...

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Main Window", font=12)
        #                     ^^^^^ 
        self.label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.button_window = ButtonWindow(self)
        #                                 ^^^^
        ...
```